# Find maximum size array that can be allocated

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

I have a simple question:

Below I'm filling an array with random values and finding the Max. I'd like to know the maximum size of the array that I can define (as the command line argument), without getting an OutOfMemory Exception. Right now I'm  trying to alternate between big and small values in a binary search kind of way.

Any better solutions? And also.. what determines this value in a practical system?

> > java Arrays 7890000  ===> 
> >     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
> >
> > java Arrays 7890  ===> Max is    0.9999444707701561

```
  public class Arrays {
      public static void main(String[] args ) {
      int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

      //Initialize to rnadom values between 0 and 1 
      double[] a = new double[N];
      for ( int i=0; i<N;i++) 
        a[i] = Math.random();

      //find the maximum 
      double max = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
      for (int i = 0;  i < N ;i++)   
        if(a[i] > max ) max = a[i];
      System.out.println("Max is    "+max);
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean alternate between big and small? Wouldn't going 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 .... be better until you hit out of memory. Then binary search between where it failed and the highest before.

Comment: Thats right.. well i know that it fails for 8000000, passes for 7000000.

Comment: This really depends on how much memory the OS is allocation to the JVM

Comment: using the system I just described I was able to narrow it down pretty quickly. output: 33554432
25165824
23068672
22544384
22413312
22380544
22364160
22355968
22354944
22354432
22354304
22354272
22354264
22354263

Comment: What are you trying to do, find the maximum element, or find the largest array?  If one, why bother with the other?

Comment: The max element part is distracting, I agree. I was trying to get at what @Cruncher did, and understand what determines this number.

Comment: The size of the object you can create is limited to the size of the largest available chunk of contiguous storage in the heap.  Even if the heap is several times larger in total, there may be reasons why an object cannot be allocated to cross some storage segment boundary or some such.

Comment: I also don't understand what the goal of this is. If it's finding the maximum of `n` random numbers from `U(0,1)`, then you don't have to allocate them. If it's finding the largest allocable array, it depends on the command-line arguments, most importantly on the heap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large arrays are placed in the tenured space and it is the longest continuous region which can be allocated after a GC is performed or Integer. MAX_VALUE which determines the maximum size. There is no way of knowing what this is without triggering a GC and you don't know what you might get without an OOME. Ie unless you get one you might have allocated more.

This seams like you are going about it the wrong way. You should only be allocating memory if you need it so you shouldn't be trying to see how much memory you don't need you might get.

if you have a 64-bit JVM you can store your data in a off heap in a memory mapped file and you are only limited by the free space on your drive which could be TB.

Comment: I suppose you could play with `freeMemory()` to get an idea... Wouldn't the GC try to compact the heap, leaving all available space in a contiguous block?